# Find $\int_0^4\int_{0}^{4}xy \sqrt{1+x^2+y^2} \,dy\, dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I am having a tough time figuring this one out.

Any help will be appreciated. do we have to approximate, or can we actually find it

Answer (score 1):

I got it :

First substitute : $x^2+y^2+1 = u$, Note that $x$ is constant.

$ $

Then substitute $17+x^2 = u$ and $1+x^2 = p$ in two different integrals that you get after that.

$ $

You should get the answer $$\dfrac{1-578 \sqrt{17}+1089 \sqrt{33}}{15} $$

Comment: Next time, just edit your original post. :) Nice work!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\int xy\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2} \,dy = \frac{1}{3} \left(x^2+y^2+1\right)^{3/2} + C$$

Comment: It's easy to see...;)

Comment: Why the downvotes? This trick can be used to solve the entire thing (at least it's theme)

Comment: @TylerHG It is easy to see because there is a quantity with $y^2$ to a power with a $y$ on the outside. It is simple to verify that the same quantity with $y^2$ raised to another power will differentiate to the form in the question. Or just use a substitution. I also suspected that this problem is homework so I didn't want to write a complete proof showing how to integrate.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with

$$\int_0^4\int_0^4 xy\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}\;\text{d}y\,\text{d}x$$

we can remove the x from the first integral because technically it's a constant inside the inner integral.

$$\int_0^4x\int_0^4 y\sqrt{1+x^2+y^2}\;\text{d}y\,\text{d}x$$

Let $u= 1+x^2+y^2$ and $\text{d}u_y=2y\;\text{d}y$. Note that when $y=0, u=1+x^2$ and when $y=4, u=17+x^2$. These implies that $y\;\text{d}y=\text{d}u/2$ and we can write our integral as

$$\int_0^4x\int_{1+x^2}^{17+x^2}\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{u}\;\text{d}u\,\text{d}x$$

Pulling the $1/2$ all the way out and computing the inner integral we get

$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^4x\frac{2}{3}u^{3/2}|_{1+x^2}^{17+x^2}\;\text{d}x$$

Simplifying some

$$\frac{1}{3}\int_0^4x\left[(17+x^2)^{3/2}-(1+x^2)^{3/2}\right]\;\text{d}x$$

Distribute the x and break up the integral over the minus sign

$$\frac{1}{3}\left[\int_0^4x(17+x^2)^{3/2}\;\text{d}x-\int_0^4x(1+x^2)^{3/2}\;\text{d}x\right]$$

Now we just perform two subsitutions and get

$$\frac{1}{3}\left[\int_{17}^{33}\frac{1}{2}u^{3/2}\;\text{d}u - \int_1^{17}\frac{1}{2}v^{3/2}\;\text{d}v\right]$$

Which we can simplify further to

$$\frac{1}{15}\left[u^{5/2}|_{17}^{33}-u^{5/2}|_1^{17}\right]$$

It's not pretty but

$$\frac{1}{15}\left[33^{5/2}-2(17^{5/2})+1\right]\approx258.245...$$