# Find $\int_0^{2}\int_0^{2}\left(x^2-2xy \right)\sqrt{1+4x^2+4y^2} \hspace{2mm} dydx$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I am having a tough time figuring this one

All help is appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by find? Find a "closed form" solution satisfying some constraints? Or are you asking if the integral exists? Also where did this integral come from?

Comment: Find an approximate upto 4 decimal, but if you can find a closed form, that would be cool

Comment: The middle integral can be evaluated in terms of logarithms and polynomials. Then integrating that, the whole thing can be evaluated in terms of more logarithms, polynomials and some inverse trig functions. So basically it's expressible in terms of elementary functions, although it's really messy. I would probably just use a symbolic integral calculator, doing it by hand doesn't seem very practical.

Comment: Note also that you can use what you did in this question ( http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860786/find-int-04-int-04xy-sqrt1x2y2-dy-dx ) to calculate one of the terms.  The only new part is dealing with $ \ \iint  \ x^2 \ \sqrt{1+4x^2+4y^2} \ \  dy \ dx \ $ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, split the integral and change the order of integration as
$$ I = \int_0^{2}\int_0^{2} x^2\sqrt{1+4x^2+4y^2} \hspace{2mm} dxdy - 2\int_0^{2}y\int_0^{2}x \sqrt{1+4x^2+4y^2} \hspace{2mm} dxdy = I_1+I_2 . $$

For the inner integral of $I_1$ you can use integration by parts with $u=x$ and for the inner integral of $I_2$ use the substitution $u=x^2$.

Comment: thanks for that, it makes sense, i will try it

Comment: @user155188: You are welcome. Work the problem step by step.